# Fragment test for fragment with nested navigation graph

Tags: android, androidx, android-architecture-navigation

[image]

Below is my navigation structure.

```
MainActivity
|- MainNavHost
   |- Fragment 1
   |- Fragment 2
   |  |- NestedNavHost
   |  |  |-Fragment A
   |  |  |-Fragment B
   |- Fragment 3
```

I want to write a fragment test(launchFragmentInContainer) for Fragment 2.

I want to assert navigation from Fragment 2 to fragment 3

```
/* fragment2.xml */
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:defaultNavHost="true"
app:navGraph="@navigation/nested_graph" />

/* Fragment2.kt */
class Fragment2 : Fragment(R.layout.fragment2), FragmentA.Listener {
    
    override fun navigateToFragment3() {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fragment2_to_fragment3)
    }
}

/* FragmentA.kt */
class FragmentA : Fragment() {
    
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        requireView().setOnClickListener{
            (parentFragment?.parentFragment as? Listener)?.navigateToFragment3()
        }
    }
}

/* Fragment3.kt */
class Fragment3 : Fragment() {
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }
}

interface Listener {
    fun navigateToFragment3()
}
```

But my test fails, saying that you cant navigate from nested graph(Fragment A) to Fragment 3. please find below the error log.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.test:id/action_fragment2_to_fragment3 cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.test:id/fragmentA) label=Additional class=com.test.info.fragmentA
at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:940)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:877)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1169)
at com.test.navigate(NavigationClient.kt:76)
at com.test.navigation.NavigationClientBase$DefaultImpls.navigate$default(NavClient.kt:79)
at com.test.Fragment2.onViewCreated$lambda-1(Fragment2.kt:34)
at com.test.Fragment2.$r8$lambda$hXZMY5lNDkQ-WfH6BWHRHQUX6r0(Unknown Source:0)
at com.test.Fragment2$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.onChanged(Unknown Source:4)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:133)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:151)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:309)
at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveDataScopeImpl$emit$2.invokeSuspend(CoroutineLiveData.kt:99)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveDataScopeImpl$emit$2.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveDataScopeImpl$emit$2.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code for navigation?
I think the problem is that you're trying to navigate to fragment3 from fragment A which are not on the same nav_graph, you should use inside your fragment A

```
requireActivity().findNavController(R.id.yourNavHost).navigate(R.id.yourAction)
```

edit :https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#wxfwwgpdu7nkya8k91wnd

Comment: I updated the question with some code snipper

Comment: I have no problem with the code you posted, are you using 2 separated nav graphs? I updated my answer with the navs i used

Comment: Yes, i am using 2 nav graphs. Exactly the same https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#wxfwwgpdu7nkya8k91wnd

Comment: Can you upload your project to git so I can give a rapid check?